# Raspberry pi on TV for gaming

Tags: networking, windows, android, android-things

I am looking forward to buy a rasberry pi but I am confused can it do the following things I want.

Can I use it as an Android for making my TV smart. ( I have HDMI in my TV. It's a led tv 3 years old and has wifi and LAN port )

Can I dual boot it so that I can play my PC games with controller attached to my raspberry pi? Like from parsec or any other software? ( Looking forward to play GTA V , Portal , Inside , etc

I have my PC in my other room and I want to work on my PC while it streams the game on raspberry pi when I work? ( I have ryzen 5 with 8gb ram and 1050ti )

Any interesting projects I can do with raspberry pi for home use?

Comment: If you want to dual boot you could just use two SD cards.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna use an Android OS, I believe you are better off just invest on any Android TV Box.

If you are familiar with kodi to stream TV channels on a computer, then you certainly can do the same thing with kodi on an Rpi running the Linux OS. Afterall, an Rpi is also a computer.

Comment: Yeah but I want to switch from Android to a Linux desktop to use parsec for gaming sometimes . Like I want to know how can I setup my raspberry pi to play on my TV and meanwhile work on my PC too. Like I know streaming is like the game runs on my PC too and the same is displayed on TV but I don't want that more like 2 separate monitors one for gaming and one for work with the help of raspberry is it possible

Comment: Since an Rpi (when runs on a Linux OS) is basically an embedded computer with limited hardware resources, you can basically configure it the way you do on a Linux desktop computer. For instance, I have a small private LAN with a NAS to serve some Linux desktop computers (run on debian OS), an Rpi0 (also runs on a debian OS) piggyback on a Seagate Dockstar, etc. Most software I installed on my desktop computer can also be installed on my Rpi0. When my Linux desktop computer is fully loaded, I can just SSH into my Rpi0 and use it do to some tasks I usually do on my Linux desktop computer.